# Buxtehude as English idiom

Tags: english-to-german, idiom

In German, there is the idiom `Buxtehude` which describes a place that may or may not exist. But I was astonished, when I read it as an idiom in an article of ars technica.

Is this a common idiom in English as well? If yes, when did it transfer?

I also noticed that it isn't used in the same way in the article as I would use it in German. What exactly is its meaning?

Quote from ars technica (emphasize mine):

> But his lecture ended with an impressive performance, from memory, of a piece made from a baroque-style repeating arpeggiation where the root of the chord changed from measure to measure based not on a conventional harmonic progression, but on the digits of π. The result was an intriguingly disorienting congress of order with randomness, **evoking something like an inebriated Buxtehude**.
>   [Original article](http://arstechnica.com/science/2016/03/mathematics-meets-music)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieterich_Buxtehude

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about music :)

Comment: @CarstenS OK, I've never heard of this composer... Then this makes totally sense xD... Should I delete this question or leave it here for people having the same problem? And if I should leave it, could you answer it?

Comment: To me, it’s a question about English. Still off topic.

Comment: @Armin Don't delete it, the community will either close and/or migrate it. Also I think that deleting questions is bad for your account/privileges.

Comment: Buxtehude is actually a town in germany. But in my opinion you use the word with a different meaning. I you talk about buxtehude you generally speak about something, somewhere with no fixed or known place. I my ears it has something like a negative touch as well.

Comment: @MeisterSchnitzel yeah, like I said in my question, a place that may or may not exist. But here, they don't talk about the city but about the composer, which makes sense.

Comment: @Maasumi as far as I remember, no they don't. And closed questions with no accepted answer are deleted by the system anyway. So, in a year, at most, this question won't exist anyway. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222

Comment: I implied that that *could*, not that it *would* happen, that's why I also used "or". That is correct, but it harms your account if you delete it yourself (after several deleted questions you're not allowed to ask any more, or something like that).

Comment: Well, I learned something, I had never heard of him either.